# Java - String - Comparação

Tags: java, string

Eu não estou entendendo uma comparação simples que estou fazendo, mas que não esta executando como eu acho que deveria.

#### Situação

Eu solicito que o usuário digite o nome da pessoa, e capturo com `String nome = scan.next();`

E envio para esta função :

```
// FIND PESSOA
private boolean findPessoaInList(String nome){
    Boolean _return = false;
    for(Pessoa p : this.pessoas){
        if(p.getNome() == nome){
            _return = true;
            // return true;
        }
    }
    return _return;
}
```

que verificar se a pessoa já esta cadastrada.
Contudo nunca cai entro do `if` mesmo se o nome já existir na lista.

#### Codigo `getNome` em `Pessoa`

```
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
```

Se alguém puder me explicar o que esta acontecendo agradeço.

Comment: Vc ja considerou utilizar o metodo equals ao inves do operador ==?

Comment: Não nem lembrei deste metodo desculpe, eu sempre programei em PHP e javascript na qual comparação é feita com `==` ou `===`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você utilizar `==` ele vai comparar com os endereços de memória, se você quiser comparar apenas os valores utilize o `.equals()`. Outra atenção é no `case sensetive`, se você digitar alguma letra minúscula e usar `equals` sendo a outra maiúscula vai dar `false`, para evitar isso utilize `equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
String nomeMinusculo = "maicon";
String nome = "Maicon";

System.out.println(nomeMinusculo == nome); // false
System.out.println(nomeMinusculo.toUpperCase() == nome.toUpperCase()); // false
System.out.println(nomeMinusculo.equals(nome)); // false
System.out.println(nomeMinusculo.toUpperCase().equals(nome.toUpperCase())); // true

/* Sugerido pelo Filipe Gonzaga */
System.out.println(nomeMinusculo.equalsIgnoreCase(nome)); // true
```

### [Ideone Exemplo](https://ideone.com/uYXZMj)

No seu caso

```
// FIND PESSOA
private boolean findPessoaInList(String nome){

    // remover espaços a direita e esquerda
    nome = (nome == null) ? "" : nome.trim();

    Boolean _return = false;
    for(Pessoa p : this.pessoas){
        if(p.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(nome)){
            _return = true;
            // return true;
        }
    }
    return _return;
}
```

Comment: Utilize o String.equalsIgnoreCase ao invés do toUpperCase() - se a intenção for ignorar case sensitive.

Comment: @FilipeGonzagaMiranda Atualizado com sua sugestão, obrigado.

Comment: Magina @MaiconCarraro, estamos aqui pra compartilhar conhecimento mesmo! :)